# How can i set the unique constraint based on the other column value

Tags: sqlite

I write the following script for customer domain maintenance .in my script i want to modify in the table . if the status is active i want to set the unique constraint to the port field .else if the status is Inactive i don't want to unique constraint.how can i set this constraint based on the other column value..? Please help me..!

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---" #name of the database
read databasename

echo " --- enter the table name --- " #name of the table
read table_name

sqlite3 $databasename.db "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;"

sqlite3 $databasename.db  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE,Created_on default CURRENT_DATE,cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);" #table creation


echo " --- Enter the total number of customer records do you want ---"
read cus_count # number of rows value


echo "--- Enter the following details one by one---"

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
port_num=8080
declare -a customer

for((i=1;i<=cus_count;i++))
do


echo "enter the $i customer details"

echo "---Enter the customer name---"
read c_name

d_name=${c_name,,}
#echo $d_name

customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_domain from $table_name where cus_domain like '$d_name';")

for cus in "${customer[@]}"
do

if [[ $d_name != $customer ]];

then
    echo "---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---"
    read c_status

if [[ "$port_num" == "$port_num" ]]; then
       port_num=$(($port_num + 1))

c_domain="$c_name"


sqlite3 $databasename.db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name (cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}\",\"${c_status,,}\",\"$port_num\") ;" 
fi


else
    echo -e "${RED}!!!OOPS for you entered customer name already  domain name assigned!!!${NC}"
    echo -e "${RED}Please enter new customer name${NC}"

i=$(($i - 1))

fi
done
done

echo " --- Records from the $table_name ---"

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name;"
```

Comment: So you want to do some changes without a unique constraint getting in the way. Then you want to start using the unique constraint. What do you want to happen if the constraint is violated? If that cannot happen, then why do you want to temporarily disable the constraint?

Comment: for newly entred customer details i use the inactive status port number so only i want it. @Yunnosch

Answer (score 2):

Use a [partial index](http://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html#unique_partial_indexes):

> A partial index definition may include the UNIQUE keyword. If it does, then SQLite requires *every entry in the index* to be unique. This provides a mechanism for enforcing uniqueness across some subset of the rows in a table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i ON MyTable(Port) WHERE cus_status = 'Active';
```

Comment: 1|Ajax|ajax|2017-08-19|active|8062
2|VVCOE|vvcoe|2017-08-19|inactive|8063

Comment: then after i give the following inputs

Comment: 3|vvm|vvm|2017-08-19|inactive|8063
4|ns7|ns7|2017-08-19|active|8064

Comment: finally the unique constraint for port column not working it takes the repetation values also

Comment: the output is      1|Ajax|ajax|2017-08-19|active|8062
2|VVCOE|vvcoe|2017-08-19|inactive|8063
3|vvm|vvm|2017-08-19|inactive|8063
4|ns7|ns7|2017-08-19|active|8064

Comment: what can i do for that above issue

Comment: You said you do not want uniqueness for inactive rows.

Comment: please modify my script i can't understand this index